# selenium auto login failed no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

we have  website([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) which will redirect to auth.exmaple.com for authentication.  i have tried following code. but it doesn't work due to unable to location username/password properly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from time import sleep

username = input("Enter in your username: ")
password = getpass("Enter your password: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.example.com")

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_name("submit")
login_button.submit()

**Error:**
   username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
  File "/Users/sababathy_c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "/Users/sababathy_c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Users/sababathy_c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/sababathy_c/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 10.16.0 x86_64)

User Name

<input type="text" name="username" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="username/email" autocomplete="off"

Password
<input type="password" name="password" class="auth0-lock-input" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off"

Submit
<button class="auth0-lock-submit" name="submit" type="submit" aria-label="Log In" style="background-color:
```

[HTML parameter details attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6slSt.png)

Comment: Looks to be in iframe, check once and let me know

Comment: Agree with @cruisepandey. Look whether the element is inside an iframe or a frame-set.

Comment: i dont understood.. could you explain bit clear

Comment: @cruisepandey i checked no iframe configured.

Comment: @Saba9t8t3 :  See below!

Answer (score 1):

If there's no frame or iframe involved, then it could be cause element is not rendered properly. Please try with Explicit waits :

Instead of

```
username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)
```

try this :

```
username_textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username")))
username_textbox.send_keys(username)
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `//*[@name='username']` xpath and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.